# Why did the Community bot delete this question?

Tags: support, specific-question, unanswered-questions, community-user

https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/posts/48307/revisions
We can see that the Community bot has deleted the question. It has to be undeleted through voting again.
Can the Mods please clarify why it was deleted and how could the bot delete a question that is not having a negative score?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It was automatically deleted under the algorithm called **Remove Abandoned Questions**

Visit [Enable automatic deletion of old, unanswered, zero-score questions after a year?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92006/260388) for more information.

> If the question is more than `365` days old, and ...
>
> - has a score of 0 or less, or a score of 1 or less in case the owner's account is deleted
> - has no answers
> - is not locked
> - has view count <= the age of the question in days times 1.5
> - has 1 or 0 comments
> - isn't on a meta site
>
> ... it will be automatically deleted. These are "abandoned" questions (`RemoveAbandonedQuestions`).

Feel free to use [the timeline feature](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/posts/48307/timeline) whenever you wanted to know the history of actions belong to particular post.

E.g. here you can observe:

[image]

Comment: Bot has been given too much power