# Is there any way to get the list of Abandoned Questions on our site?

Tags: discussion, recent-activity

Recently I wanted to ask a question related to Saraswati Devi and I searched for one of my old questions and learned that the question was deleted due to less activity. You can find more details from [this link](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2387/why-did-the-community-bot-delete-this-question).

Although this process is for the betterment of the site, it has some drawbacks. Keeping the drawbacks aside, it is better if users of our community can search for those questions that have chances to go into the abandoned list in order to make them active.

Is there any provision to get the *list of such questions* on our main site other than manually checking based on the metrics provided?

Comment: You can make a query with the filters mentioned [here](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2388/647) on data Stackexchange.